# difference between Specificed and Test Memory frequency

Tags: memory

I want to buy 1 single piece of 8 GB ram for motherboard [GA-B75M-D3H](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4150#sp) . I've found one G.Skill one([here](http://www.flipkart.com/g-skill-nt-ddr3-8-gb-1-x-gb-pc-ram-f3-1600c11s-8gnt/p/itmdfa6npcngznzm?pid=RAMDFA3ZJWVWCVRE&ref=e26e1b6d-fc8d-4201-aac4-9d59ae5859ad)) which shows : DDR3-1600/PC3-12800.

If you scroll down a bit you'll find:

```
 Memory
 Frequency  1333 MHz (Specified), 1600 MHz (Test) 
 Technology
    DDR3 SDRAM Memory
```

I'm confused by seeing 1600 Mhz (Test) ... whether it's original frequency is 1333 or 1600. I think I shoud prefer those having frequency of 1600 than those having lower than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically they tested that ram bar and its speed shown as 1600mhz.